# Consequences of applying PCA before logistic regression

Tags: logistic, pca

I am doing a machine learning assignment and I have been asked a question that I have no idea about. I have read my notes and also some posts online, but I can not find anything related. Any idea about how to deal with this?

> Having a dataset with labels, where we apply PCA to 2D and 3D as
>   feature transformation, will it improve, reduce or have no effect on
>   performance if we use Logistic Regression to classify the data?

Comment: What do you do once you diagonalize the covariance matrix?

Comment: I multiply the matrix of data and the matrix V (taking only the first n columns, where n is number of features I want)

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by "apply PCA:" could you be specific about what you would do?  In particular, how many principal components would you retain?

Comment: Also, is this about performance on in-sample or out-of-sample data?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596036/relationship-between-logistic-regression-and-principal-component-analysis